# Stored procedure sends email even when condition is false. Any ideas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When a user uses our site to process certain requests, upon exiting the site, an email with a link goes out to that user asking him/her to click the link to take a survey and share his/her user experiences with us.

Below is the stored procedure that I have written that does as described above.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[SendSurvey] 
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @sender nvarchar(200)
    declare @dept nvarchar(200) = ''
    declare @loc nvarchar(200) = ''
    declare @dteCreated nvarchar
    declare @RequestID nvarchar(50) = ''
    declare @authorizedname nvarchar(200) = ''
    declare @email nvarchar(200) = ''
    declare @message nvarchar(1000) = ''
    declare @mailid int = 0

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;

    SELECT 
        @email = email, @mailid=ID, @message = @message, 
        @RequestID = RequestID,
        @authorizedname = SUBSTRING(submittedBy, CHARINDEX(',', submittedBy) + 1, LEN(submittedBy) - CHARINDEX(',', submittedBy) + 1)
        + ' ' + SUBSTRING(submittedBy, 1, CHARINDEX(',', submittedBy) - 1),
        @loc = Bldg, @dtecreated = DateCreated, @dept = Department
    FROM 
        Survey
    WHERE 
        email = @email
        AND Email IS NOT NULL OR Email != ''
        AND (orderStatus != 1)

    SELECT @message = 'This is a computer generated email message.
            Please DO NOT use the REPLY button above to respond to this email.

            Dear '+ @authorizedname +':

            Thank you for using the order processing system.

                Please click the link below to complete a survey

            http://feedbacksurvey.php?rID=' +@RequestID+'&loc='+Replace(@loc,' ', '%20')+'&dept='+Replace(@dept,' ', '%20')+'

            Regards, 
           web admin.' 

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @profile_name = 'Customer Feedback Survey',
          @recipients = @Email, -- your email
          @subject = 'Customer Feedback Survey',
          @body = @message;

    UPDATE Survey 
    SET orderStatus = 1 
    WHERE orderStatus != 1 AND ID = @mailid
END
```

There are two problems with the stored procedure.

1. There is a column `orderStatus` which is a `BIT` data type with True (1) of false(0) value.

   If the `orderstatus` is false, then send emails with records associated with it.

   After sending the email, update `orderstatus` to true so the email doesn't get sent a second time.

   This is not working. When I execute the stored procedure where all records on the table have orderstatus set to True, email still goes out.
2. the second problem that I am having is that the code is not sending out all records where `orderStatus` is True. It just sends email one at a time.

We would like emails to be send out for ALL records where orderstatus = 1 (True).

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Of course it sends an email regardless of the status, you don't have any kind of condition around that code.

Answer (score 2):

You mixed AND with OR in your WHERE clause.  The results will include all rows where `Email != ''`, regardless of the other conditions.

Use parens to make this work:

```
WHERE email=@email
AND (Email IS NOT NULL or Email != '')
AND (orderStatus != 1)
```

As for why it's sending one email at a time, you are using your query to populate scalar variables.

```
SELECT @email = email...
```

Will result in `@email` being populated with one value, no matter how many rows the query returns.

Comment: @Tab_Alleman, thanks for your response.

Initially, I was using this method to send all emails:

`SELECT @email = @email +;+email...`. However, every recipient would see the other recepients emails.

Comment: Just so you know, I tried your method and email still went out. Only difference this time is that there is NO name on the TO field and there is no name on the Dear...

Comment: That's because you had a row in your table that had a value for email, but no value for "submittedBy".   If you don't want that to happen, you should put a similar condition in your WHERE clause for the submittedBy column.

Answer (score 0):

> the second problem that I am having is that the code is not sending out all records where orderStatus is True. It just sends email one at a time.

Yeah - that's how `sp_send_dbmail` works. You'll need a cursor to send > 1 email.

```
DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
  SELECT ....
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO ....
WHILE @@FETCHSTATUS = 0 BEGIN
  EXEC sp_send_dbmail ...
  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO ....
END
CLOSE c
DELLOCATE c
```

Comment: thanks so much for your response. I was actually using cursor but when I tried testing it, I was getting some strange error but I can't remember the error now. I will try yours and get back if I run into issues.

Also, will using cursor prevent users from seeing other user's email addresses?